# Declaring an optional array argument

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering if there is any difference when setting default array value to be an empty array or NULL.

For example:

```
function arrayTest(array $array = array()) {
    if(!empty($array)) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

or

```
function arrayTest(array $array = NULL) {
    if(!empty($array)) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

What I noticed is that first example doesn't allow NULL values to be passed and the second example does because of type casting.

Any other differences? Which one should be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other difference is that if you don't pass an argument , it will default to `array()` or `null`, which are two very distinct values. You can check for that of course, but you will need to take it into account. `empty` will work for both, but a foreach loop over `null` won't work that well, and various array functions will also fail.

What you noticed is correct: Passing `null` for a typehinted argument only works if you add `= null` to the declaration. This is not only true for arrays but for objects as well. In PHP there is no way in PHP to make a typehinted argument that is mandatory but can be null. As soon as you add `=null` to the declaration, you can pass `null` but you can also omit the parameter.

If to you there is no logical difference between an empty array or null, I would choose the first method of defaulting to an empty array. Then at least you'll know that the input is always an array. I think that add clarity to both the implementer of the function and the programmer(s) who use it. But I guess that's just an opinion and not even a strong one.

My main advice would be to not make the argument optional at all. In my experience this will make the usage of such functions unclear, especially as the code grows and more arguments are added.